# Rendering XML as text for RSS feed for all browsers

Tags: xml, rss

XML is renders as text rather then a formatted RSS. Site is deployed on IIS7 (Windows Server 2012). The sample code is as following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<rss version='2.0'>
<channel>
<title>Site Title</title>
<link>http://iep036s:3648/Pages/TTV.aspx</link>
<description>RSS feed for the Video list.</description>
<lastBuildDate>Sat, 25 Jan 2014 20:31:01 GMT</lastBuildDate>
<generator>Description</generator>

<item>
<title >Title</title>
<link>http://iep036s:3648/Pages/Detail.aspx?Id=262</link>
<description>Description</description>
<pubDate>Wed, 16 May 2012 00:00:00 GMT</pubDate>
<guid isPermaLink='true'>http://iep036s:3648/Pages/Detail.aspx?Id=261</guid>
</item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it's served from your ISS server with the right `Content-Type` header: `application/rss+xml`.

Comment: I have made this change, now it works on IE. But still same issue (XML is renders as text) on Google Chrome and Firefox. Please note that I am not sure that how but this same XML file renders as formatted RSS (on IIS7+Win Svr2008) using `Content-Type` header: `text\xml`.